# Do I need to query the .Result property of a ValueTask that I choose to not await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, valuetask

Let's say I have a method that returns an object of type `ValueTask`, for example the `WaitToReadAsync` method on `ChannelReader`. There are three ways I can consume this `ValueTask`. I can either:

1. Directly await it.
2. Turn it into a Task, then await it (with `.AsTask()`)
3. Query the `.Result` property if it has completed synchronously (if `.IsCompleted` is `true`).

With regards to the third method (calling `.Result` on the ValueTask), the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1.result?view=net-6.0) states that this property can only be queried once. But, does this property need to be queried at all? In other words, is it okay to never query the result of a `ValueTask`?

Here is an example of what I mean:

```cs
var channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<int>();
var waitToReadValueTask = channel.Reader.WaitToReadAsync(default);
if (waitToReadValueTask.IsCompleted)
{
   if (channel.Reader.TryRead(out var result))
   {
      // Do something with the result object.
   }
}
```

In this example, the `waitToReadValueTask` was never consumed. It was never awaited, neither was the `.Result` property called on it. Is this okay?

Comment: What would happen if your `waitToReadValueTask` has completed but you cannot read from the channel?

Comment: @JohanP `waitToReadValueTask` will only complete if something has been written to the channel. Hence, in my example I only call `TryRead` if `waitToReadValueTask` is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. Yes, it is perfectly OK to omit querying the [`Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1.result) property of a `ValueTask<T>`, provided that you are not interested about the result, or about the `Exception` that might be stored inside the task. It is also OK to ignore entirely a `ValueTask` after its creation, if you so wish, resulting in a so-called fire-and-forget task. The task will still complete, even if you haven't kept any reference of it.

In general it is a good idea to consume your `ValueTask`s though, either by `await`ing them or by `AsTask`ing them or by querying their `Result` (provided that they are already completed). By consuming a `ValueTask` you signal to the underlying implementation that the backing [`IValueTaskSource<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.sources.ivaluetasksource-1) instance can be reused. Reusing `IValueTaskSource<T>` instances is how the `ValueTask`-based APIs are avoiding memory allocations, when the asynchronous method cannot complete synchronously.

In your example you are querying the [`IsCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1.iscompleted) property immediately after creating the `ValueTask`, so it is highly unlikely that the `ValueTask` was not completed upon creation. So regarding your example the above advice has only theoretical value. `ValueTask`s that are completed upon creation are not backed by `IValueTaskSource<T>` instances, so there is no performance implication by not querying the `Result` in your example. The advice would be of practical value if you queried the `IsCompleted` property at a later time after creating the `ValueTask`.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense to me. Now I understand that querying the `.Result` property, or awaiting the ValueTask signals to the creator of the ValueTask that the backing instance of `IValueTaskSource` can be reused such that it can avoid another allocation.

In practice, I was seeing:

`if (valueTask.IsCompleted) { _ = valueTask.Result; } else { var result = await valueTask; }`